# Using Scanner.useDelimeter() in Java to isolate tokens in an expression

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I am trying to isolate the words, brackets and `=>` and `<=>` from the following input:

```
(<=>A B) OR (C AND D) AND(A AND C)
```

So far I've come to isolating just the words (see `Scanner#useDelimeter()`):

```
sc.useDelimeter("[^a-zA-Z]");
```

Upon using :

```
sc.useDelimeter("[\\s+a-zA-Z]");
```

I get the output just the brackets.

which I don't want but want `AND` `)`.

How do I do that? Doing `\\s+` gives the same result.

Also, how is a delimiter different from regex? I'm familiar with regex in PHP. Is the notation used the same?

**Output I want:**

```
(
<=>
A
(and so on)
```

Comment: It is unclear to me, what output do you expect, exactly?

Comment: for the input, I want : 
(
<=> 
A 
B
etc

Comment: Must you use delimiter? `Patter`/`Matcher` seems perfect here.

Comment: I can post an answer using  `Patter`/`Matcher`. Do you want it?

Comment: Can I try first and ask you if I need it? :)

Comment: Great! I must congratulate you on wanting to try it yourself first! Come back if you need us!

Comment: [(]|[)]|<=>|=>|\\w+ gives me the right answer. Though I did try with \\W+|\\w+, I always got ) (. So had to hardcode the <=> :/ Is it ok? or is there a way to still use \\W+??

Comment: As `\W` is the negated `\w`, it **will** match `(`, `)` and so on. I think it is ok to use the hardcoded `<=>` and others. Also, this makes your regex more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a delimitimg regex that can be zero width (because you have adjacent terms), so look-arounds are the only option. Try this:

```
sc.useDelimeter("((?<=[()>])\\s*)|(\\s*\\b\\s*)");
```

This regex says "after a bracket or greater-than or at a word boundary, discarding spaces"

---

Also note that the character class `[\\s+a-zA-Z]` includes the `+` character - most characters lose any special regex meaning when inside a character class. It seems you were trying to say "one or more spaces", but that's not how you do that.

Comment: It is very good! But it still matches `" )"` and `" ("` can you improve it?

Comment: How about `sc.useDelimeter("((?<=[()>])\\s*)|(\\s*\\b\\s*)")`?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `[]` the `^` means 'not', so the first regex, `[^a-zA-Z]`, says 'give me everything that's **not** a-z or A-Z'

The second regex, `[\\s+a-zA-Z]`, says 'give me everything that **is** space, +, a-z or A-Z'. Note that "+" is a literal plus sign when in a character class.

Comment: Thanks but when [^a-zA-Z] is used, how come I'm getting all the words? Shouldn't I be getting everything that's not a word?

Comment: What is `sc`? Anyway, you're setting the delimiter to the value of the regex, so if you set it to, for example, 'A', you'll get everything that *isn't* A, tokenized on A.

Comment: Sorry, yes it's a scanner.

Comment: That's what I thought, but Scanner doesn't have a parameterized `delimiter` method...

Comment: actually the method is `useDelimiter` and it breaks the `String` everytime it matches the pattern.

Comment: Minor error in your last statement: the char class includes the plus sign

Comment: @Bohemian I don't get what you're saying

Comment: The character class `[\\s+a-zA-Z]` includes the `+` char. You omitted to mention that in the last sentence of you answer.

Comment: No. You are completely missing the point. A "+" is literally the + character. I've edited your answer